# ArrayList items to JTable using DefaulTableModel

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to take the contents inside my ArrayList, holding FootballClub objects and display them onto my JTable. I can't seem to get this to work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It says for model.add() that an array initializer is not allowed here. My columnNames also seem to not be displaying

```
// the arraylist containing footballclub objects
protected ArrayList<FootballClub> clubs = new ArrayList<FootballClub>();


 public void displayTable(ArrayList<FootballClub> footballClubs)
{
    String[] columnNames = {"Club name", "goals", "points", "wins"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < footballClubs.size(); i++)
    {
        String name = footballClubs.get(i).getClubName();
        int goals = footballClubs.get(i).getGoals();
        int points = footballClubs.get(i).getPoints();
        int wins = footballClubs.get(i).getPoints();
        model.addRow({{name, goals,points,wins}});
    }

    final JTable teamTable = new JTable(model);
    teamTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tableview");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how what you've written doesn't work. I assume there is a compiler issue on this line:

```
    model.addRow({{name, goals,points,wins}});
```

It looks as if you are trying to use the `Object[]` overload. The correct syntax is:

```
    model.addRow(new Object[] { name, goals, points, wins });
```

Or, the special syntax for array initialisers:

```
    Object[] row = { name, goals, points, wins} ;
    model.addRow(row);
```

If there had been a `List` overload, you could use `List.of(name, goals, points, wins)`, but there isn't.

(Also note, it is conventional to use `List` instead of `ArrayList`. If there is a conflict with `java.awt.List` you can explicitly add `import java.util.List`.

The `for` can be written:

```
for (FootballClub club : footballClubs) {
```

which should make things clearer.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the question. I have used what you said it's now displaying the correct information but I still cannot  get my column names to show up for some reason. I have passed them into the DefaultTableModel constructor

Comment: @Shabaaz: the JTable needs to go into a JScrollPane in order to show the column headers.